# Fullcalendar and bootstrap - clearing remote modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I'm using `fullcalendar` to display events. Clicking on days / events displays various forms to enable me to add a new event.

The following is a basic snippet of this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   // disply the modal form
},
eventClick: function(event, element) {
   $('#popupTodoEditForm').modal({
      remote: form-edit.php,
      show: true
   });
}
```

If i select an empty day, i can add the form fine. If i click on an existing event, i can update fine.

The problem is, on subsequent clicks on empty days, the data from the previously saved new event is displayed.

The problem seems to be when the modal closes, it doesn't clear the remote form details.

Is there a way that I can reload the form without the previous data being in the form?

Thanks

Comment: Modals are basically just hidden elements. Couldn't you just clear the modal input fields on your click event before you show the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove existing modal before load again,

```
$('#popupTodoEditForm').modal('destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

`$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '#popupTodoEditForm', function() {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});`